# Найти количество чисел последовательности, которые больше первого введенного числа

Tags: python

Дана непустая последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся нулем. Ноль в последовательность не входит, служит признаком ее окончания. Найти количество чисел последовательности, которые больше первого введенного числа

Код:

```
z = int(input())
count = 0  
n = 100
while n != 0:
    n = int(input())
    if n > z:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: В чём проблема?

Comment: В том что код не работает и проходит 40% тестов))

Comment: @Mikey_mouse А для чего там `n`, которое равно 100?

Comment: `if n != 0 and n > z:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
first_num = int(input())
counter = 0
item = int(input())
while item != 0:
    if item > first_num:
        counter += 1
    item = int(input())
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
arr = []
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    arr.append(n)

res = len([i for i in arr if i > arr[0]])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

вот тоже решение

```
z = int(input())
sum(map(lambda x: 1 if int(x) > z else 0, iter(input, '0')))
```

Answer (score 0):

может подойдет

```
n = int(input())
count = 0
while n > 0:
    count += n
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        print(count)
```

Comment: Ответ похоже считает что-то совершенно другое